# Sharepoint Office 365 videos don't show up in IE11

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

We are using Sharepoint 365 and the videos do not show up at all in IE11.  There is a large space where the video would appear, but nothing displayed.  The answer isn't "Use a different browser" although I'd love that to be the answer, but we have to support IE11.  I hope someone has a workaround - we can't be the only ones with this problem!

Comment: Which exact version of IE 11 you are using for making this test? I tested the issue with IE 11.1.18362.0 and video is playing without any issue.https://i.postimg.cc/jj0mskPv/319.png I check the source of the site and found that <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> is already there in the source. You can check whether there is any update available for your IE 11 browser. If any available then try to update it and make a test again. Also check the console to see whether there is any error or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, you have to do one of the workarounds discussed in [this community thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Stream-Forum/Stream-embed-on-Sharepoint-2016-in-IE11-doesn-t-work/m-p/288626).

> After adding this to SP16th masterpage it worked fine.
>
> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">`